# Java8: Matching and mapping with reference to this

Tags: java, list, java-8, java-stream

Suppose to have an object from the class `Target` and a set of objects from the class `FriendOfTarget`, e.g.

```
public class Target{

    private List<FriendOfTarget> completeListOfFriendOfTargets;

    public boolean matchSomething(FriendOfTarget fot){
        //do something by comparing the fields of Target and FriendOfTarget
    }

    public List<FriendOfTarget> reduce(){
        //
    }

}

public class FriendOfTarget{
    //
}
```

If I want to construct a list of `FriendOfTarget` objects, in Java7 I do the following inside the method `reduceByParam` from class `Target`:

```
public List<FriendOfTarget> reduce(){
  List<FriendOfTarget> lst= new ArrayList<>();
  for(FriendOfTarget fot: completeListOfFriendOfTargets){
    if(reduceByThis(fot))
      lst.add(fot);
  }
  return lst;
}
```

How can I do the same in Java8? I have some difficulties to find examples on how to refer to `this` into the `anyMatch` method of a `stream`.

Comment: Is there a typo in the second listing and it should be _reduceByParam_ instead of _matchSomething_. I don't see any code related to _anyMatch_ and where there is a problem with _this_.

Comment: Yes, you are right! Please, yours is the honor: edit my question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to implement a functional interface, that refers to *this*:

- Lambda expression: `fot -> reduceByThis(fot)`
- Method reference: `this::reduceByThis`

A lambda expression can access `this` in the same way as the enclosing scope. That means you can invoke the method `reduceByThis` both with and without qualification. For the method reference, that target object can be explicitly bound. The following example only shows the latter:

```
public List<FriendOfTarget> reduce() {
    return completeListOfFriendOfTargets
        .stream()
        .filter(this::reduceByThis)
        .collect(toList());
}
```

You can also use `this` explicitly in lambda expressions. As I have already mentioned, it refers to the `this` of the enclosing scope (in contrast to anonymous inner classes). For example:

```
public List<FriendOfTarget> reduce() {
    return completeListOfFriendOfTargets
        .stream()
        .filter(fot -> fot.reduceOtherDirection(this))
        .collect(toList());
}
```

Comment: Ups! You are right. Because it was not an int param originally, it was this!